# Does scikit-learn train_test_split preserve relationships?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I am trying to understand [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/another-twitter-sentiment-analysis-with-python-part-4-count-vectorizer-b3f4944e51b5) code. I do not understand how if you do:

```
x_validation, x_test, y_validation, y_test = 
  train_test_split(x_validation_and_test, y_validation_and_test...
```

you can later do:

```
(len(x_validation[y_validation == 0])
```

surely the `train_test_split` means `x_validation` and `y_validation` aren't related. What am I missing?

EDIT:
There are some good answers already but I just want to clarify. Are `x_validation` and `y_validation` guaranteed to be in the correct order, and the same as each other. Obviously you could add a row to either and mess things up, but is there an underlying index that means order is preserved? I come from a non-python background and sometimes you could not guarantee order of things like SQL columns.

Comment: ```x_validation``` and ```y_validation``` is what you test your model on. They should be related I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely do want the `x_validation` to be related to the `y_validation`, i.e. correspond to the same rows as you had in your original dataset.
e.g. if Validation takes rows 1,3,7 from the input x, you would want rows 1, 3, 7 in both the `x_validation` and `y_validation`.

The idea of the `train_test_split` function to divide your dataset up into a two sets of features (the `x`s) and the corresponding labels (the `y`s). So you want and require

```
len(x_validation) == len(y_validation)
```

and

```
len(x_test) == len(y_test)
```

Looking at other parts of you question that might be causing confusion:

`y_validation == 0`

will generate a boolean mask of `True` and `False` values that you can use to select only those rows from any data frame with the same length, so in this case it will also work with `x_validataion`.

As an aside,

```
len(x_validation[y_validation == 0])
```

Seems a slightly confusing way of counting the number of examples that are of class `0`. I would have gone for

```
(y_validation == 0).sum()
```

myself and then you can write the % negative calculation as

```
100*(y_validation == 0).sum()/len(y_validation)
```

which Is a bit neater to me.

Answer (score 1):

`train_test_split` takes `n` random indexes from the length of your data, and returns the values at these indexes in `xtrain`, `ytrain`, or whatever you pass. Look at this simple demonstration:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = np.random.randint(0, 10, 15) 
target = data**2
indices = np.arange(15)

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest, indicestrain, indicestest = \
    train_test_split(data, target, indices)

print(data)
print(target)
print(indices)
```

```
[7 7 4 1 1 3 1 6 8 2 2 1 9 9 9] # random val between 0 and 10
[49 49 16  1  1  9  1 36 64  4  4  1 81 81 81] # their squared values
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]  # the index in the original array (data)
```

Now, take some random indices from these, and let's see if they keep being related:

```
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest, indicestrain, indicestest = \
    train_test_split(data, target, indices)

print(xtrain)
print(ytrain)
print(indicestrain)
```

```
[9 9 2 1 8 2 4 7 1 6 7]
[81 81  4  1 64  4 16 49  1 36 49]
[12 14 10 11  8  9  2  1  3  7  0]
```

As you can see, the second row is the squared of the first, meaning that the order was preserved.